# react-redux-firebase V3 issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I got error

> Error: Context from react-redux not found. If you are using react-redux v6 a v3.*.* version of react-redux-firebase is required.

I try steps in reference documentation, I did upgrade `react-redux-firebase` to version `3.0.0-alpha.6`, but it did not work, I try downgrade `react-redux` to `4.4.9` but the same problem is still exist;

My JSON file

```
{
    "name": "clientpanel",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase": "^5.8.1",
        "react": "^16.7.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
        "react-redux": "6.0.0",
        "react-redux-firebase": "2.2.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-firestore": "^0.6.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
    ]
}
```

How to fix error?

Answer (score 0):

Download v3 as following:

```
npm i --save react-redux-firebase@latest
```

Then you can refactor your code to work with v3 as written here in the docs: https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/tree/next

2- Or just use `react-redux v5.1.1`

```
npm i --save react-redux@^5.0.0
```

Comment: thank you for the information, but i still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same error and some TypeErrors just like you.

I think if you are using latest versions of `react-redux-firebase` and `redux-firestore`
the changed the way of using their provider so you might want to use the `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider` imported from `react-redux-firebase` and wrap your App component inside it, instead of using the `reactReduxFirebase` in your createStore function.

you might wanna take a look at this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62537595/10763842