# object is not a function when calling `useFirestoreConnect`

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I'm using `react-redux-firebase` and `redux-firestore` packages.
I'm trying to connect firestore to redux using the `useFirestoreConnect` hook, but after calling this hook it gives me a TypeError like in this picture.
I've searched in the GitHub issues, docs and here but I'vent fount any solution.

The error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

you see the whole error in this picture:

[The console.log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Comlt.png)

[The TypeError returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJzdR.png)

Comment: Please paste the text of the error into your question so others can help you more easily.

Comment: I've shared a picture of the whole error, but ok I added the text!

Comment: Great, the text of the error helps but now we need to see the code that is producing this error so someone can help you debug.

Comment: The error is occurred when I call the `useFirestoreConnect` imported from `react-redux-firebase`. 
like this:
`useFirestoreConnect(["products"])`

Comment: Does the json object have more elements? I ask you this because in the image that you shared, the last element is “doc: userId,” it has a comma, and if it is the last element, the comma should be eliminated, could you share more code?

Comment: It's not about that, even without the doc it's not working. I tried calling the function as they mentioned here: [link](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/api/useFirestoreConnect.html) but its not working, I guess it's about version of firebase and redux, I opened an issue on their repo in GitHub about that.
I want you to know this, just calling the function the error will appear, and the function is written as they mention on their docs, so it's not about the syntax you mentioned! @EnriqueDelValle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello guys I figure out where the problem coming from.
This is for anyone who is looking for a solution.

1. `react-redux-firebase` and `redux-firestore` are having some issues
   in versions compatibility, so to skip that I installed the latest
   version of the packages!
2. Clearly there were some differences between old versions and the new
   ones of giving your app the `redux firebase provider`.
   The old way might look like this:

   ```
   const store = createStore(
   rootReducer,
   composeEnhancers(
   reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig),
   reduxFirestore(firebase),
   applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore }))
   )
   );
   ```

but if you want to implement hooks in your app and use the `useFirestoreConnect` this will not work.
In new versions you need to remove the `reactReduxFirebase` and `reduxFirestore` from your `createStore` func and instead use the `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider` imported from `react-redux-firebase` and wrap your app inside it, like this:

```
<ReduxProvider store={store}>
   <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
     <BrowserRouter>
       <AuthIsLoaded>
         <App />
       </AuthIsLoaded>
     </BrowserRouter>
   </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
</ReduxProvider>
```

and passed props: firebase, react-redux-firebase config and any other things you wan. the rrfProps are lik this:

```
const rrfProps = {
firebase,
config: rrfConfig,
dispatch: store.dispatch,
createFirestoreInstance, //since we are using Firestore
};
```

and this is the react-redux-firebase config (rrfConfig):

```
const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: "users",
  useFirestoreForProfile: true, // Firestore for Profile instead of Realtime DB
  attachAuthIsReady: true, // attaches auth is ready promise to store
};
```